# Есть ли разница между выражениями !!( a && b ) и (a && b)?

Tags: javascript

В тесте встретил данный вопрос, ответил "нет" так как считаю, что двойное отрицание должно вернуть то же самое значение, но правильный ответ "да", подскажите почему.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Для начала приведу немного теории.**

На самом деле, в JavaScript логические операторы `||` и `&&` работают особым образом.

Оператор `||` возвращает *первый из операндов*, значение которого может быть приведено к логическому `true`. Если же оба операнда приводятся к логическому `false`, то оператор `||` вернет *последнее значение*.

```
console.log('foo' || false); // 'foo'
console.log(null || 'bar'); // 'bar'
console.log(false || 1); // 1
console.log(false || null); // null
```

Это позволяет использовать всеми любимый широко известный хак со значением переменной по умолчанию:

```
function f(arg) {
    var a = arg || 0;
    // ...
}
```

Оператор `&&` возвращает *первый из операндов*, значение которого приводится к логическому `false`. Если же оба операнда приводятся к `true`, то оператор `&&` вернет *последний операнд*.

```
console.log(true && []); // []
console.log(null && 'foo'); // null
console.log(0 && 'foo'); // 0
console.log('foo' && 'bar'); // 'bar'
```

Что касается конструкции `!!`, то она используется для явного приведения операнда к логическому типу:

```
console.log(!!'foo'); // true
console.log(!!''); // false
console.log(!!0); // false
console.log(!!1); // true
```

---

**Вернемся к вашему вопросу.**

Как вы уже могли догадаться, разница между выражениями

```
!!(a && b); // (1)
(a && b); // (2)
```

заключается в **типе** возвращаемого значения. Если обе переменные `a` и `b` оба имеют логический тип, то эти выражения эквивалентны. В общем же случае, тип результата выражения `(2)` определяется типом операндов, тогда как выражение `(1)` всегда возвращает значение логического типа.

Answer (score 5):

Наверное потому что в случае !!(a && b) происходит преобразование в boolean. А в случае (a && b) не происходит.